# How to call function from button using visual basic and mvc core

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to create a button to call methods using visual basic and MVC in visual studio 2019,
when I try to make it the button, didn't response

below the view code and controller code
P.S. OPenCaseController it's my controller and init() it's the function I want to call using the button

```
@Code
    Layout = Nothing

End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>init</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div Class="form-group">
        <form method="post" action="OPEN">
            <Button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("OPenCaseController", "init")'">  OPENhysys  </Button>
            <input type="text" name="x" />
        
  
                </form>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

here the controller code using visual basic

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports Aspentech
Imports Aspentech.HYSYS
Namespace Controllers
    Public Class OPenCaseController
        Inherits Mvc.Controller
        Dim hyCase As SimulationCase
        Dim hyApp As Aspentech.HYSYS.Application
        Function init() As ActionResult
            ViewData("Message") = "Your contact page."

            Return View()
        End Function

        <HttpPost()>
        <ActionName("OPEN")>

        Public Function init(x) As ActionResult
            ViewData("Message") = "Your contact page."
            hyApp = CreateObject(“HYSYS.Application”)
            hyCase = hyApp.SimulationCases.Open(“E:\otts\st st trial-reem.hsc”)
            hyCase.Activate()
            Return View()

        End Function


    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Hi @ReemElshenawy, please check your application, whether it is an Asp.net core MVC web application or not.  Because, as far as I know, at present the in the Visual studio, there is no template to create a VB asp.net core MVC application, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuSse.png). So, I assume perhaps you create an MVC application with the .Net Framework, instead of Asp.net core. If that is the case, the issue still relates [the `@Url.Action()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Comment: hello @ZhiLv thanks for your answer but I already using the asp.net framework VB but there is no  asp.net core support VB so I don't know what to do, and I solve the problem of `@url.Action()` method  but it didn't work

Comment: No matter Asp.net Framework and Asp.net core, the @Url.Action() will work well with them, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2zr6.gif), the application is an Asp.net Framework application, as we can see that the code works well.

Comment: yes it's working well and every thing work open the next view and write the message

Comment: @ZhiLv um so sorry for my late replay but it's just working by add another view and call the button from another value thank you for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <Button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("OPenCaseController", "init")'"> OPENhysys </Button>
> ```

The issue relates the `@Url.Action()` method, if you right click this method and choose the "Go To Definition", you can see the first parameter should be the action name, and then the second parameter is the controller's name, like this (the screenshot is captured from a C# application):

[image]

More detail information about `@Url.Action()` method, check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Besides, in an MVC application, even though the controller **file name** is "OPenCaseController", the controller's name should be "OPenCase". More detail information about MVC application, check [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

So, try to change the above code as below:

```
<Button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("init", "OPenCase")'">  OPENhysys  </Button>
```

Comment: hi @zhiLv unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem when I toggle breakpoint at the `init()` post function didn't get into it

Comment: Hi @ReemElshenawy,  "when I toggle breakpoint at the init() post function didn't get into it", please check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGSkD.png), whether your application root file directory looks as that. And open the RouteConfig file to check whether you are using the default route. Besides, you can also use F12 developer Console and Network tools to check if there have any error.

Comment: yes, I checked on them and the route config is typical as your screenshot I think there's a problem with HttpPost and HttpGet in my code?

Comment: You could check it. But since you are using the `location.href` to change the request url, it will call the Get method, check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dziZe.gif). When using F12 developer Console and Network tools to check the web page, is there any error? If the Console tools don't have any error, and in the Network, it doesn't contain the request, I assume the browser disabled JavaScript. Since you are using the JavaScript to redirect to another page, if the browser disabled JavaScript, the button click event will not work. So, please check your browser setting.